# How can I apply a unique filter to partition column of a parquet file using wr.s3.read_parquet?

Tags: python, pandas, aws-data-wrangler

I have a parquet dataset stored in s3 and I want to read it to apply a filter to the partition field, specifically the unique. I was trying as follows, however the unique function cannot be applied

Here's my attempt:

```
query_fecha_dato = "{0}fecha_dato={1}/".format(param.delivery["output_path"], fecha_dato_formato)
print(query_fecha_dato)
df_fecha_datos = wr.s3.read_parquet(path=query_fecha_dato,dataset=True,filters=[('fecha_dato','unique',fecha_dato)])
print(df_fecha_datos.head(5))
```

It should show only the partition column "fecha_dato", however it shows the following:

```
nro_de_pedido nro_de_negocio  ... nrootchex ingest_date
0    2006968078      635922336  ...        -1  2022-08-06
1    2006968079      635912195  ...        -1  2022-08-06
2    2006968080      635921361  ...        -1  2022-08-06
3    2006968081      635922792  ...        -1  2022-08-06
4    2006968082      635922368  ...        -1  2022-08-06
```

I want to obtain only the partition column "fecha_dato" without duplicates

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docu](https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs/awswrangler.s3.read_parquet.html) I cannot find `filters` as an option.

It looks like to select only `fecha_dato`, you need to specify `columns=['fecha_dato']`. Furthermore I don't see a unique option in awswrangler, but you can use pandas `drop_duplicates` afterwards

```
df_fecha_datos = wr.s3.read_parquet(path=query_fecha_dato,dataset=True,colums=['fecha_dato']).drop_duplicates()
```

should work - at least as long as you do not get multiple dataframes back from s3.

This downloads all values in `fecha_dato` and only drop the duplicates locally, but I have no good idea how to save this bandwidth without deploying some compute resources in AWS.

Comment: Hello thank you very much! I added the line of code, however I got the following error:[INFO] 2022-12-13T14:14:31.793Z 84d08f6e-cec5-4a83-9e2a-261822db63f1 Se agrego  06.12
s3://entel-datalake-cl-landingzone-dev/itrc_delivery_breighstar/fecha_dato=2022-08/
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
[]
[ERROR] 2022-12-13T14:14:31.980Z 84d08f6e-cec5-4a83-9e2a-261822db63f1 Error: 'fecha_dato'
[INFO] 2022-12-13T14:14:31.980Z 84d08f6e-cec5-4a83-9e2a-261822db63f1 Error

Comment: This looks like it cannot find the column. Are you sure the column `fecha_dato` exists? A common gotcha is also that it might contain whitespaces like `fecha_dato     `.